# Upgrade Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20 to latest

Tags: ionic2

I have an existing app I built on Windows/Android with `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`.  I cannot get any `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` apps, including vanilla (`ionic start`) to work on OSX. As a result I think I need to upgrade from `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` to the latest version of Ionic 2.

Can anyone recommend a good guide to do so?

I am worried that I break my existing app, because I know some of the structure has changed in the latest version.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I run:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

expecting it to upgrade to the latest version of Ionic.

As you can see below, `Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7` is the latest. But why does it still have: `Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11`, is this the latest version of the framework?

```
Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

**UPDATE**

Now my Windows environment has errors trying to upgrade Ionic. Any advise appreciated:

```
E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo>ionic info
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Richard\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-fda00e1c
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-fda00e1c' -> 'C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-fda00e1c' -> 'C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice would probably be to create a blank project with the latest version, then copy and paste your code into there. Before you do so, read these release-notes (tells you about `ngModule` and all other changes) https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-rc0-2016-09-28

Since `RC.0` nothing has changed much. But the upgrade to `RC.0` was quite a bit of trial and error before everything works again. (f.e. `<ion-navbar primary>` became `<ion-navbar color="primary">`
)

Read them carefully, if you understand what has changed a bit, copy and paste your pages into the `src` folder, update the `ngModule` and change your code to the release-notes.

*(I would first try to serve your blank project, if that fails something is wrong with ionic cli (maybe double  install), but this could just save you from thinking your project was updated badly instead of that your cli is bugged)*

**edit**

My own versions: (works with latest `RC.3`)

```
$ ionic info

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v4.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I will do the upgrade in Android and then build it ob OSX.

Comment: If I am doing an upgrade, I figure I should get the latest versions of all components in the process. As far as Node is concerned, should I go for `Node v6.9.2 LTS` or `Node v7.2.1 Current`?

Comment: Edited the answer, I'm not sure about that one, I myself use `v4.5.0`, not sure about the capability of node with ionic but you could try

Comment: As a side note to node: I was using node v4.X and have just upgraded to Node v6.9 LTS.
I would recommend to always upgrade to LTS version because these are stable long term versions. The current version will change very quickly.
On the main question: Ivaro has provided a good answer and you should go with it. Depending on how much you have built, it can take you time to upgrade/debug this because of all the breaking changes. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, well I don't think Node will be the issue here, but it's good to stay up to date (and it might be).

Comment: I am getting errors trying to upgrade the Windows environment now. I have updated the description above. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like your npm is trying to install new nodemodules over old ones, delete the folder `Appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules` and try again

Comment: Did you do what the message said?
Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Yes I do try `npm install -g cordova` but get the same errors. I am busy deleting `Appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules` now, and will try again.

Comment: after deleting `node_modules`, `npm install -g cordova` ran successfully. Thank you